# how to display some sort of error or warning if assigning to a non-existent vue data property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue for front end development, and I have the following script:

```
<script>
import PostService from '../PostService';

export default {
  name: 'Post',
  data: function() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      text: ''
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async CreatePost() {
      await PostService.CreatePost(this.text);
      this.post = await PostService.GetPosts(); **//How to get error here?**
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

the problem is I keep misspelling things (like post instead of posts), but vue is not displaying any sort of error/warning, how can I get vue to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, this is the tricky part and I believe there is no way to detect it.

Only solution I see is to use Vue.js with TypeScript, that will help to catch a lot of errors early and significantly improve quaity of your code in application.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an editor function I think. I use VSCode so I can only speak to that, but if you do as well I use the Vetur extension and I've been very happy with it.